# OpenAI stream response in java

Tags: java, kotlin, okhttp, openai-api

The OpenAI `chat/completions` API supports a stream response by passing `stream=true`. This enables the response to come in chunks of data rather than one full response. It will be similar to how ChatGPT outputs answers.

I see similar question for different languages or tech stack (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73547502/how-do-i-stream-openais-completion-api)). But I can't find a full example of how to implement that in java (or kotlin) with `OkHttp` client.

How do get OpenAI's API response in form of stream?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code, now ChatGPT can fully realize streaming conversation in the console via Java.

```
import com.theokanning.openai.completion.chat.*;
import com.theokanning.openai.service.OpenAiService;
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import java.util.*;

public class Starter {
    // Create a new OpenAiService instance with the given API key
    public static OpenAiService service = new OpenAiService("Your API Token");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Streaming chat completion...");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
        // Create a list of ChatMessage objects
        List<ChatMessage> message = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();
        message.add(new ChatMessage(ChatMessageRole.USER.value(), userInput));
        // Create a ChatCompletionRequest object
        ChatCompletionRequest chatCompletionRequest;
        boolean running = true;
        // Run the loop until the user enters "exit"
        while (running) {
            chatCompletionRequest = ChatCompletionRequest
                    .builder()
                    .model("gpt-3.5-turbo")
                    .messages(message)
                    .n(1)
                    .maxTokens(500)
                    .logitBias(Collections.emptyMap())
                    .build();
            // Create a Flowable object to stream the chat completion
            Flowable<ChatCompletionChunk> flowableResult = service.streamChatCompletion(chatCompletionRequest);
            // Create a StringBuilder object to store the result
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            // Subscribe to the Flowable object and print the result
            flowableResult.subscribe(chunk -> {
                chunk.getChoices().forEach(choice -> {
                    String result = choice.getMessage().getContent();
                    if (result != null) {
                        buffer.append(result);
                        System.out.print(choice.getMessage().getContent());
                    }
                });
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> System.out.println());
            // Get the user input
            userInput = scanner.nextLine();
            // Add the user input to the list of ChatMessage objects
            message.add(new ChatMessage(ChatMessageRole.SYSTEM.value(), buffer.toString()));
            message.add(new ChatMessage(ChatMessageRole.USER.value(), userInput));
            // Exit the loop if the user enters "exit"
            if (userInput.equals("exit")) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
        service.shutdownExecutor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

this is the okhttp with java to recieve the stream response from ChatGPT:

```
 public static void okHttpEvent(SseEmitter emitter, String prompt, String openAiKey) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://{open-api-address}/v1/chat/stream/completions?q=" + prompt + "&eid=" + RequestContext.getRequestId())
                .build();
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(@NonNull Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request original = chain.request();
                        Request request = original.newBuilder()
                                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + openAiKey)
                                .header("Accept", MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM.toString())
                                .method(original.method(), original.body())
                                .build();
                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                })
                .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();

        RealEventSource realEventSource = new RealEventSource(request, new EventSourceListener() {

            @Override
            public void onOpen(EventSource eventSource, Response response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(EventSource eventSource, String id, String type, String data) {
                try {
                    HttpUrl url = eventSource.request().url();
                    String reqId = url.queryParameter("eid");
                    SseChatService.getInstance().appendMsg(data, reqId);
                    emitter.send(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    emitter.completeWithError(e);
                    log.error("send sse to client error", e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onClosed(EventSource eventSource) {
                emitter.complete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(EventSource eventSource, Throwable t, Response response) {
                emitter.completeWithError(t);
                log.error("event source failure", t);
            }
        });

        realEventSource.connect(okHttpClient);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a working example using the `Flux` module, it is similar to `OkHttp` so hopefully it can help.

The example consumes an Open AI chat stream and sends it back to the client. Make sure to set the `openAIAPIKey` variable to your key.

```java
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import org.springframework.http.*;

// ... class code

public Flux<Object> chatStream(OpenAIChatBody requestBody) {
  try {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setBearerAuth(openAIAPIKey);
    WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://api.openai.com/v1");
    // Send the request to openAI
    return client.post()
      .uri("/chat/completions")
      .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
      .bodyValue(requestBody)
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
      .map(dataBuffer -> dataBuffer.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
      .concatMap(chunk -> {
        String[] lines = chunk.split("\n");
        return Flux.fromArray(lines)
          .filter(line -> !line.trim().isEmpty())
          .map(line -> line.replace("data:", "")
            .replace("[DONE]", "")
            .replace("data: [DONE]", "")
            .trim());
      })
      .filter(data -> !data.isEmpty())
      .concatMap(data -> {
        try {
          Map<String, Object> resultObject = new ObjectMapper().readValue(data, Map.class);
          // return data - you can parse the resultObject to whatever it is that you need
          return Flux.just(resultObject);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
          return null;
        }
    });
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

You will need to include the following dependencies in the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- ... other dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- This is for flux to stop displaying a potential DNS warning for MACs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.73.Final</version>
        <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

All of this code can be found in a working [file](https://github.com/OvidijusParsiunas/deep-chat/blob/main/example-servers/java/springboot/src/main/java/com/server/openAI/OpenAIService.java) in the following example [project](https://github.com/OvidijusParsiunas/deep-chat/tree/main/example-servers/java/springboot).