# How to send POST request from html to python app and receive stream data

Tags: python

I hope someone can help me:
My index.html page: https://example.com/index.html, it includes a 'message' input and 'send' button, when the 'send' button is clicked, message will send to https://example.com/python_app/ (the folder of app.py) by POST method, then python app will return stream data back to https://example.com/index.html, and it append word by word to div output of index.html page (like chatgpt).
Now, The error show in Console, Network tab of browser is:
python_app, POST , 200 OK then
python_app , GET , 405 Method Not Allowed
Please help me.
app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import time
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def handle_message():
  message = request.form["message"]
  words = message.split()
  def event_stream():
    for word in words:
      time.sleep(1)
      yield "data: {}\n\n".format(word)
  return Response(event_stream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

And index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="messageInput" />
  <button id="sendButton">Send</button>
  
  <div id="output"></div>

  <script>
    $("#sendButton").click(function() {
      var message = $("#messageInput").val();
      
      $.ajax({
        url: "/python_app/", 
        type: "POST",
        data: {message: message},
        success: function(res) {
          var eventSource = new EventSource("/python_app/");
          eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
            $("#output").append(event.data + "<br>");
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have already tried this, but error is 404:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

words = []

@app.route("/python_app/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def handle_message():
  if request.method == "POST":
    message = request.form["message"]
    words.extend(message.split())   

  elif request.method == "GET":
    def event_stream():
      for word in words:
        time.sleep(1)
        yield "data: {}\n\n".format(word)
    return Response(event_stream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Comment: in which route you are getting response code 405 ?

Comment: sse doesn't support post.  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911862/4744864

Comment: @MijanurRahaman I see in the developer tab of Chrome when access index.html page